# Java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, wildfly-15

I'm starting a project in JEE and when i try to use EJB, I got errors on deployement.

I have tried many things but nothing works.

Here are my logs :

```
2021-01-26 23:54:14,903 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.7.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:15,248 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.5.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:15,254 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:15,350 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 15.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 7.0.0.Final) starting
2021-01-26 23:54:15,352 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.class.path = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 56.0
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;native;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.1/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ffmpeg\bin;;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32;;.
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 12.0.2+10
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 12
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 12.0.2
    java.version.date = 2019-07-16
    java.vm.compressedOopsMode = 32-bit
    java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 12
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 12.0.2+10
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    jboss.bind.address = localhost
    jboss.bind.address.management = localhost
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final
    jboss.host.name = msi
    jboss.modules.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = msi
    jboss.qualified.host.name = msi
    jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = msi
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\logging.properties
    module.path = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log
    org.jboss.logmanager.nocolor = true
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows 10
    os.version = 10.0
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = JBossTools: WildFly 15
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = org.jboss.modules.Main -mp C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\modules org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = 
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    user.country = FR
    user.dir = C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\alexa
    user.language = fr
    user.name = alexa
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = Europe/Paris
    user.variant = 
2021-01-26 23:54:15,354 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: WildFly 15 -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules=java.se -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
2021-01-26 23:54:15,876 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.7.0.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,292 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found projet-SAJ.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called projet-SAJ.war.dodeploy
2021-01-26 23:54:16,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2021-01-26 23:54:16,579 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.6.5.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,584 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.5.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,609 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,612 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,615 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 core threads with 192 task threads based on your 12 available processors
2021-01-26 23:54:16,618 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,622 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.6.2.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2021-01-26 23:54:16,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
2021-01-26 23:54:16,631 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,647 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.15.Final starting
2021-01-26 23:54:16,652 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
2021-01-26 23:54:16,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.11.Final)
2021-01-26 23:54:16,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
2021-01-26 23:54:16,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2021-01-26 23:54:16,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2021-01-26 23:54:16,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2021-01-26 23:54:16,746 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:16,746 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-8) Converted [2] config entries and added [4] replacements
2021-01-26 23:54:16,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2021-01-26 23:54:16,758 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-8) Converted [3] config entries and added [18] replacements
2021-01-26 23:54:16,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2021-01-26 23:54:16,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 192 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 48 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/DSServeurJava]
2021-01-26 23:54:16,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
2021-01-26 23:54:16,852 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2021-01-26 23:54:16,855 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2021-01-26 23:54:17,057 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
2021-01-26 23:54:17,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
2021-01-26 23:54:17,078 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
2021-01-26 23:54:17,082 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
2021-01-26 23:54:17,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
2021-01-26 23:54:17,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "projet-SAJ.war" (runtime-name: "projet-SAJ.war")
2021-01-26 23:54:17,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar")
2021-01-26 23:54:17,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2021-01-26 23:54:17,183 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
2021-01-26 23:54:17,186 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\Users\alexa\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
2021-01-26 23:54:17,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2021-01-26 23:54:17,230 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2021-01-26 23:54:17,265 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 268 435 456
2021-01-26 23:54:17,271 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
2021-01-26 23:54:17,291 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2021-01-26 23:54:17,292 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2021-01-26 23:54:17,293 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2021-01-26 23:54:17,294 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2021-01-26 23:54:17,331 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
2021-01-26 23:54:17,331 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2021-01-26 23:54:17,368 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
2021-01-26 23:54:17,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for projet-SAJ
2021-01-26 23:54:17,577 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment projet-SAJ.war
2021-01-26 23:54:17,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2021-01-26 23:54:17,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
2021-01-26 23:54:17,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2021-01-26 23:54:17,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
2021-01-26 23:54:17,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/DSServeurJava]
2021-01-26 23:54:17,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'projet-SAJ.war#projet-SAJ'
2021-01-26 23:54:17,631 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: projet-SAJ
    ...]
2021-01-26 23:54:17,720 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2021-01-26 23:54:17,721 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2021-01-26 23:54:17,723 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.14.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:17,748 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.3.Final
2021-01-26 23:54:17,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2021-01-26 23:54:17,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2021-01-26 23:54:17,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2021-01-26 23:54:17,894 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2021-01-26 23:54:17,896 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2021-01-26 23:54:17,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ServicesPersonneBean' in deployment unit 'deployment "projet-SAJ.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/projet-SAJ/ServicesPersonneBean!fr.dauphine.mido.as.projet.ejb.ServicesPersonneBean
    java:app/projet-SAJ/ServicesPersonneBean!fr.dauphine.mido.as.projet.ejb.ServicesPersonneBean
    java:module/ServicesPersonneBean!fr.dauphine.mido.as.projet.ejb.ServicesPersonneBean
    ejb:projet-SAJ/ServicesPersonneBean!fr.dauphine.mido.as.projet.ejb.ServicesPersonneBean
    java:global/projet-SAJ/ServicesPersonneBean
    java:app/projet-SAJ/ServicesPersonneBean
    java:module/ServicesPersonneBean

2021-01-26 23:54:17,928 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."projet-SAJ.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."projet-SAJ.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "projet-SAJ.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@7.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:394)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:385)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:552)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.<clinit>(ClassFile.java:385)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.SerializationHackProxy.proxy(SerializationHackProxy.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.HandleDelegateImpl.<init>(HandleDelegateImpl.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.bindService(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@7.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2416)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:392)
    ... 16 more

2021-01-26 23:54:18,008 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221007: Server is now live
2021-01-26 23:54:18,008 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.6.3.jbossorg-00014 [default, nodeID=a3eac872-6013-11eb-92ca-58a023cd5906] 
2021-01-26 23:54:18,030 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2021-01-26 23:54:18,031 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
2021-01-26 23:54:18,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2021-01-26 23:54:18,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2021-01-26 23:54:18,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0119: Unbinding connection factory named java:/JmsXA to alias java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2021-01-26 23:54:18,137 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-2) AMQ151007: Resource adaptor started
2021-01-26 23:54:18,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2021-01-26 23:54:18,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
2021-01-26 23:54:18,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0118: Binding connection factory named java:/JmsXA to alias java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2021-01-26 23:54:18,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2021-01-26 23:54:18,172 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projet-SAJ.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"projet-SAJ.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"projet-SAJ.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override"}}
2021-01-26 23:54:18,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "projet-SAJ.war" (runtime-name : "projet-SAJ.war")
2021-01-26 23:54:18,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar")
2021-01-26 23:54:18,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."projet-SAJ.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "projet-SAJ.war"

2021-01-26 23:54:18,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2021-01-26 23:54:18,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2021-01-26 23:54:18,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2021-01-26 23:54:18,217 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 15.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 7.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 3574ms - Started 448 of 634 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 343 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I'm using Wildfly 15 and jdk 14.0.1

also the empty code of my bean (already tried without a constructor and it's the same) :

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ServicesPersonneBean {

    public ServicesPersonneBean() {}

}
```

If someone can help me please !

Comment: Try Java 11 instead, I'm not sure WildFly 15 is properly running on 14.

Comment: thanks ! it works !